# webpack 2 sort entry array by alphabet

Tags: javascript, build, webpack, frontend, webpack-2

How disable webpack-2 sorting entry array?
My code look like this:

```
   entry: {
     bundle: [./js/helpers/API/stringAPI.js','./js/helpers/API/callbackAPI.js' ] 
   }
```

but webpack sort array and I have something like this:

```
 [0] ./js/helpers/API/callbackAPI.js 4.29 kB {0} [built]
 [1] ./js/helpers/API/stringAPI.js 1.03 kB {0} [built]
```

Can I disable this sort?

Comment: Do you find solutions?

Answer (score 0):

webpack has stats options: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/stats/#stats

try this:

```
stats: {
  assetsSort: false,
  chunksSort: false,
  modulesSort: false
},
```

Comment: this just control what bundle information gets displayed. But in bundle.js  we have first './js/helpers/API/callbackAPI.js'